# How to check the internet Connection in iPhone without Reachability classes?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I want to check the internet connection in my iPhone without the use of Reachability Classes. i want to constantly check the connection when a particular event is triggered in my view. I also want to determine if the connection is from a Wifi or through 2G or 3G connection. I have  already tried using Reachability classes. But these classes just return the value if the Wifi is On (Though the net cable is unplugged from the Wifi Router). I have tried

**[Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection]**

and

**[Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:@"www.google.com"];**

But the above methods doesn't seem to work properly inspite of network disconnections.

Also is there any way we can determine the type of netwrok 2G or 3G in iOS6? I know that we have Core Telephony Framework that works only in iOS 7. But i just want to know if i can determine the cellular network iOS 6.0. Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

Working code without reachability classes and also working in iOS 6:

```
- (NSNumber *) dataNetworkTypeFromStatusBar {

    UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    NSArray *subviews = [[[app valueForKey:@"statusBar"] valueForKey:@"foregroundView"]    subviews];
    NSNumber *dataNetworkItemView = nil;

    for (id subview in subviews) {
        if([subview isKindOfClass:[NSClassFromString(@"UIStatusBarDataNetworkItemView") class]]) {
            dataNetworkItemView = subview;
            break;
        }
    }
    return [dataNetworkItemView valueForKey:@"dataNetworkType"];
}
```

**And the value keys I've found so far:**

> 0 = No wifi or cellular
>
> 1 = 2G and earlier?
>
> 2 = 3G?
>
> 3 = 4G
>
> 4 = LTE
>
> 5 = Wifi

Or in iOS7 use `CoreTelephony` framework

```
CTTelephonyNetworkInfo *telephonyInfo = [CTTelephonyNetworkInfo new];
NSLog(@"Current Radio Access Technology: %@", telephonyInfo.currentRadioAccessTechnology);
[NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter addObserverForName:CTRadioAccessTechnologyDidChangeNotification 
                                                object:nil 
                                                 queue:nil 
                                            usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) 
{
    NSLog(@"New Radio Access Technology: %@", telephonyInfo.currentRadioAccessTechnology);
}];
```

Comment: First, I've seen that method floating around before so I'm pretty sure it works and people probably do use it. However, to me, it looks like an awfully fragile/dangerous method. Not only are you accessing things that Apple hasn't directly given you access to, you're also accessing things that could change with any OS release (even minor point releases) causing undesired results at best and crashes at worst. I'd also be worried about including the `UIStatusBarDataNetworkItemView` string in your code since that's a private class and Apple could reject your app for referencing it.

Comment: The above code works but as @MikeS suggested we may end up getting rejected by Apple. Is there any other way we can get another solution?

Comment: @PradeepReddyKypa As of iOS7 there is a builtin framework that helps you do this. See my updated answer

Comment: @Ty_ Ya i have seen that. I am aware of it. I have mentioned the same in my question as well. I am just looking out for a way to implement the same in iOS6.0 as well. Any help would be very helpful yaar.